# error when changing the language top menu

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to change the icon when the phone language changes.
Use this code to draw the top menu.
If the language changes to the phone, the exit icon will be flipped.

The icon would look like this if the language of the phone is Arabic and its natural form.
[image]

The icon will look like this if the language of the phone is English and it is not normal and inverted
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/back"
        android:icon="@drawable/menue_backe"
        android:title="close"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

```
 public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.toolbar_menub, menu);
            return base.OnPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.back:
                    //do something

                    Finish();

                    return true;

            }
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        //
```

Comment: Hi , not understanding about this *If the language changes to the phone, the exit icon will be flipped.* . Do you mean a animation of back button when menu item changed ?

Comment: If the primary language of the phone is Arabic, and it is changed to English.

Comment: The icon appears inverted, not basically

Comment: @ALLE According to your description, you mean that you run your android app, then set this app in background, changing phone device language, finally the android app menu icon changed? If not, how do you change language?

Comment: Cherry Bu .The language is changed by the user to the entire phone. It is not an option to apply by app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a try with follow ways to change Back button icon ：

```
ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
ActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Mipmap.Icon); // here modify the image as your need
```

Then modify it by laugnge in needed **Activity** :

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();

    string locale = Locale.Default.Language;
    //System.Console.WriteLine("-----"+locale);
    if (locale == "en")
    {
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Mipmap.Icon);
    }
    else
    {
        // other language
    }
}
```